# Min and Max Date not working with react-native-neat-date-picker

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to set min and max date. But it's not working. Can you any one help me how to set those values.
Sample i tried:

```
<DatePicker
       minDate={new Date('03-19-2022')}
       maxDate={new Date('03-21-2022')}
       isVisible={this.state.isShowEndRangePicker}
       mode={'single'}
       onCancel={ this.onCancel }
       onConfirm={ this.onConfirm }
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The date format you are using is wrong:

YYYY-MM-DD should be the one to go for otherwise javascript throws you an error.

> minDate={new Date('2022-03-19')}
> maxDate={new Date('2022-03-21')}

should work.